# How do I enable the pngcairo terminal in Gnuplot

Tags: terminal, png, gnuplot

I would like to plot a figure to PNG format (avoiding using convert), however my Gnuplot distribution does not offer the PNGCAIRO terminal. How can I install/enable it? I use Gnuplot 4.4, patchlevel 2 on Mac OS X 10.6.

```
[me]machine @ test $ gnuplot

G N U P L O T
Version 4.4 patchlevel 2
last modified Wed Sep 22 12:10:34 PDT 2010
System: Darwin 10.8.0

Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2010
Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
faq, bugs, etc:   type "help seeking-assistance"
immediate help:   type "help"
plot window:      hit 'h'

Terminal type set to 'x11'
gnuplot> set terminal pngcairo
                      ^
     unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list
```

Answer (score 20):

If you are running [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/), you can install everything with just one command line

`brew install gnuplot --with-cairo`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev` is easier.

Comment: That option has been deprecated in brew instead:
`brew install gnuplot --with-cairo`

Answer (score 6):

If your package manager (e.g. `macports` or `fink`) doesn't have a suitable gnuplot, then you're probably going to need to build gnuplot from source yourself.  Gnuplot itself isn't too difficult, but if you want a specific terminal (e.g. `pngcairo`) you'll need to download and build the dependencies yourself before building gnuplot -- in this case `libcairo`.

Gnuplot also has a regular `png` terminal which should exist if your gnuplot distribution was able to find `libgd` at compile time or your package manager included it.

And easy way to tell which terminals you have enabled is to just type `set terminal` in an interactive gnuplot window.  That will print a list of all the terminals that your gnuplot is able to use (which depends on the libraries it was compiled with)

Sorry if this isn't a lot of help.

Answer (score 6):

I upgrade gnuplot to 5.0.1 and encounter the same issue. Here is what I do.

To install gnuplot 5.0.1, download the source file from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/), and then:

```
#decompress it:
tar -xvf gnuplot-5.0.1.tar.gz

#install the dependency libraries for cairo-based terminals, like pdfcairo, pngcairo
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-dev


#build it:
cd gnuplot-5.0.1 
./configure 
make

#install it:
sudo make install
```