# How do I setup pngcairo terminal in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, cairo

I'm having the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496469/how-do-i-enable-the-pngcairo-terminal-in-gnuplot). I tried installing the libcairo library with the command

```
sudo yum install cairo-devel
```

After that, I removed and installed gnuplot through yum. I still get the same error. What else do I need to do to get gnuplot to let me use pngcairo?

I also installed pango through yum.

When I try installing gnuplot from source I get these messages in my config.log:

```
configure:11776: checking for CAIROPANGO
configure:11784: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "cairo >= 0.9.0 pango >= 1.10 pangocairo >= 1.10"
Package pango was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pango.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'pango' found
Package pangocairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pangocairo.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'pangocairo' found
```

What exactly do I add to PKG_CONFIG_PATH? I'm not even sure where to find my installed pango and cairo-devel libraries.

Comment: What OS?  Fedora maybe?  http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=250946

Comment: Note that you also need pango.  Can you get any information from `configure.log`?

Comment: Oops -- sorry.  The file is `config.log`.  You should look for lines that say something about `pango` or `cairo` or `pangocairo`, etc.

Comment: I'm on Red Hat. I have pango and cairo-devel installed through yum, but when i install gnuplot, it doesnt find them. When I try to make gnuplot from source, it doesnt see the libraries either, and if I try to build them myself, it just sends me to dependancy hell. I'll add the relevant lines from config.log

Comment: try `locate pango.pc` and `locate pangocairo.pc`.  If locate finds something, that's great news.  add it to the path -- (assuming you're in bash), something like `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:/path/to/pango.pc` (without the `pango.pc` part) might help.

Comment: And when you say you have pango, I assume that means that you have pango-devel (i.e. you have the header files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pango only provides the runtime libraries. For the development files, you need to install *pango-devel*:

```
$ sudo yum install pango-devel
```

When in doubt about package names, use:

```
$ sudo yum search foo
```

where *foo* is what you are looking for. *yum* will search in names, descriptions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

libcairo features are available by default in gnuplot 4.4 or later. 
The gnuplot44 package can be found in the epel repository: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Answer (score 0):

Before compile it, install the dependency libraries for cairo-based terminals, like pdfcairo,

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-dev
```

---

The full steps to install gnuplot 5.0.1:

Download the source file from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/), and then:

```
#decompress it:
tar -xvf gnuplot-5.0.1.tar.gz

#install the dependency libraries for cairo-based terminals, like pdfcairo
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-dev


#build it:
cd gnuplot-5.0.1 
./configure 
make

#install it:
sudo make install
```