# Gnuplot: linetype Version 5.0 patchlevel 3

Tags: svg, png, gnuplot

I am using gnuplot 5.9 patchlevel 3 and I wanted to use different `lt` thus I wanted to reproduce the following this [tutorial](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/lines_arrows.html) from gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 1.

In particular if I copy it and launch it both from term and as .eps I couldn't see dashed lines, here the output [image: example]

In particular I do not understand the following line:

`You will only see dashed lines if your current terminal setting permits it`

What does it mean? How I can 'force' gnuplot to print the different dashed lines in .eps, .png or via screen?

I found [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/793/) guide but its refer to a 4.2.5 version of gnuplot, even if I use:

`set termoption dashed`
or
`set terminal x11 dashed`

I can't see the dashed lines...Those are the terminals I can use in gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 3 from `help term`:

> ```
> canvas            cgm               context           corel
> dumb              dxf               eepic             emf
> emtex             epslatex          fig               hpgl
> latex             mf                mp                pcl5
> pop               postscript        pslatex           pstex
> pstricks          push              qms               svg
> tek40xx           tek410x           texdraw           tgif
> tkcanvas          tpic              vttek             x11
> xlib              xterm
> ```

I red also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601348/gnuplot-png-output-doesnt-plot-dashed-dotted-lines) but gnuplot 5.0 doesn't support pngcairo (???) as a test, in fact, I just try:

`set term pngcairo dashed`

And I receive the answer:

`Terminal type set to 'unknown'
                  ^
         unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list`

Thus I tried to install pngciaro following [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496469/how-do-i-enable-the-pngcairo-terminal-in-gnuplot) using homebrew which I found not so useful unfortunately due to the fact that the question about gnuplot 5.0 does not have an answer and because I receive some warning that could be connected with the installation of the pngcairo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using gnuplot 5.9 patchlevel 3

Surely you mean 5.0.3? The image you attached shows dashed lines so what's your question? Then I tried this example script you link to with the eps terminal and it works fine as well on 5.0.3.

Gnuplot renders output using different "terminals", some of the more terminals do not support support dashed lines and this includes the default PNG terminal `png`, the png terminal from the cairo library, `pngcairo`, does however support dashed lines. Terminals must be integrated into your Gnuplot build at compile-time, so options must be flagged to enable certain terminals. If Gnuplot was not built with the cairo library then the `pngcairo` or `epscairo` terminals will not be available and you will receive that message

> unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list

when attempting to set you plot to one of those terminals.  When you do `set term` it just displays the terminals which your build was compiled with.

Gnuplot 5 *does* support pngcairo, it just has to be built with it. Are you on OSX and have homebrew installed? Just install it with cairo support using

```
brew install gnuplot --with-cairo
```